# How to use custom field from subquery in WHERE condition of upper level SELECT in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do something like this but got an error and can't get how to do the last WHERE in the right way?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT s.SupplierID, s.CompanyName, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Orders o
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Products p ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE SupplierID = s.SupplierID) AS N'Number of orders'
FROM dbo.Suppliers s
) 
WHERE 'Number of orders' > 150;
```

Comment: Please don't ask questions that say you got an error without posting what the error is. Think like a programmer. Error messages serve a purpose.

Comment: Single quotes are for strings, not identifiers; use `[` and `]` as an earlier comment suggested or double-quotes (`"`) for ANSI standard. Also, subqueries in the FROM clause must be aliased.

Comment: You don't have an alias for your main query. The Count column has no alias. You are comparing a string literal to an integer literal. You have an ambiguous column SupplierID in your inner most query. Using some formatting would go a LONG way to making this better so you can actually what is going on. The outer query is wholly unnecessary.

Comment: Look into Common Table Expressions (CTEs) instead of selecting from sub-queries. It's mostly just syntactic sugar, but it makes things easier to read and debug, and lets you refer to computed columns easily by name. I'd also suggest you use square brackets instead of confusing quoted identifiers... "AS [Number Of Orders]" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty sparse on details here but I think you are just trying to find and suppliers who have more than 150 orders. You can use a query with basic aggregation here and make this a lot simpler.

```
SELECT s.SupplierID
    , s.CompanyName
    , COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Orders o
JOIN dbo.[Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
JOIN dbo.Products p ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
join dbo.Suppliers s on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
group by s.SupplierID
    , s.CompanyName
having count(*) > 150
```

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right in my intensions. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the main expression with an alias. 
For example, this works:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS One) O WHERE One = 1
```

But this does not:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS One) WHERE One = 1
```

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT s.SupplierID, s.CompanyName, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Orders o
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Products p ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE SupplierID = s.SupplierID) AS N'Number of orders'
FROM dbo.Suppliers s
) T
WHERE 'Number of orders' > 150;
```

Also, as Uueerdo puointed out, it would be better to use [Square Brackets] instead of 'Single Quotes' to name and refer to the column [Number of orders]. I believe there is a setting that determines if single quotes are allowed, but square brackets are the standard.

Comment: Thanks. If I change '' by [] in the query - it works!